# Radio buttons checked changing submit text

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button, submit, checked

My site structure consists on an index.php which is styled by a css file. It then includes the following php code in a separate file:

```
<?php include("globals.php"); ?>
<form action="<?php echo $website.$relative_string;?>" name="subscribe" onsubmit="javascript:return checkEmail(this);" method="post">
<div id="cell8" class="titlecell2"><h3>Email:</h3></div>
<div id="cell9" class="inputcell2">
<input type="text" class="inputfield2" name="email" value="Your Email..." id="email2" maxlength="255" onfocus="this.value='';">
</div>
<div id="cell10" class="textcell3">
<input name="group" type="hidden" id="group[]" value="<?php echo $group; ?>">
<input name="subscribe" id="sub" type="radio" value="true" checked>
</span>Subscribe </p>
</div>
<div id="cell11" class="buttoncell">
<button type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Join" id="submitButton2">
<span>OK</span>
</button>
</div>
<div id="cell8" class="textcell4">
<input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="unsub" value="false">
</span>Un-Subscribe </p>
</div>
</form>
```

It appears on screen with no problems in the correct layout as my css style sheet. What I would like this to do is when I select the "Subscribe" radio button the submit button text "OK" changes to "Join". When I click on the Unsubscribe button text "OK" or "Join" changes to "Leave".

I tried to make some code from research:

```
if(document.getElementById('sub').checked) {
    document.write("<span>Join</span>"
}
else if(document.getElementById('unsub').checked) {
    document.write("<span>Leave</span>)
}
```

I think this kind of worked in that it changed to Join (replacing the OK line, but obviously didn't update on clicking unsubscribe.  I guess it would update on refreshing the page if my default wasn't join.  I guess I need to do some form of onclick but then I have no idea how to adjust that span ok bit.

Please help?
Many thanks Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in plain JavaScript without jQuery. It avoids the unnecessary overhead.

This should work, but I haven't had a chance to test it:

```
var sub = document.getElementById('sub'); // Save element to a variable, so you don't have to look for it again
var unsub = document.getElementById('unsub');
var btn = document.getElementById('submitButton2');

sub.onchange = function() //When sub changes
{
    if(sub.checked)  //If it's checked
    {
        btn.innerHTML = "<span>Join</span>"; // Set button to Join
    }
    else // If not..
    {
        btn.innerHTML = "<span>OK</span>"; // Set button to OK
    }
}

unsub.onchange = function() //When unsub changes
{
    if(unsub.checked)  //If it's checked
    {
        btn.innerHTML = "<span>Leave</span>"; // Set button to Leave
    }
    else // If not..
    {
        btn.innerHTML = "<span>OK</span>"; // Set button to OK
    }
}
```

However, you should not do it like this.

You should combine the two radio buttons into a radio group.

In that case you will listen for radio group to change, get the value of the radio group, set button text according to the value.

Comment: Hi danii, I will give this a try; I'm sure there is a group but I could have it wrong (limited understanding): <input name="group" type="hidden" id="group[]" value="<?php echo $group; ?>">

Comment: Hi Danii, it worked a treat this way.  So I'm very happy.  However am curious on your suggestions regarding radio group if you get time.

Comment: Chris, I looked at your code again and noticed that you do in fact have a form on line 2. This form is responsible to radio buttons AND input field, hence it is no longer possible to simplify the radio button selection using the form. Hence, the above solution is the best way to go! =]

Answer (score 0):

if you label your `<span>OK</span>` to something like `<span id="your_id">OK</span>` then added a class to your radio button like this `<input class="your_class" type="radio" name="subscribe" id="unsub" value="false">` them...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    

<script>
$("#your_class").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $("#your_id").text('Join');
    }else {
       $("#your_id").text('Leave');
    }
});
</script>
```

This was all written in the browser so let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Hi Kyle,  thanks for the suggestion.  I added the span id, and the your_class to both the subscribe and unsubscribe buttons.

Comment: Then added the script you wrote below the </form> tag, when I uploaded it to test, it did not update the button text.  Any thoughts?

Comment: basically your need a hook to your radio button class to perform an action when the radio value changes.  So maybe you could add a console.log('radio changed'); line in the script to see if the function is even triggering.  This will be outputted to your web browser's console.

Comment: Also, make sure the script is added outside of your form tags.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need a ; in your form method="" argument, but I'm not 100% sure.